# How can I check if an exception was raised in a Gherkin test?

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

I'm writing a scenario that checks for a timeout exception. This is my Ruby code:

```
    # Execute the constructed command, logging out each line
    log.info "Executing '#{command.join(' ')}'"
    begin
        timeout(config['deploy-timeout'].to_i) do
            execute_and_log command
        end
    rescue Exception => e
        log.info 'Err, timeout, ouch'
        raise Timeout::Error
    end
```

I'd like to check either the output for Err, timeout or if an Exception was raised in Gherkin/Cucumber.

```
Then(/^the output should be 'Err, timeout, ouch'$/) do
    puts 'Err, timeout, ouch'
end
```

How can I do that?

Comment: How does the Timeout::Error reflect your app's UI?

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you using a test tool/harness like `minitest` or `rspec` along with ruby and `cucumber`?

Comment: orde, I'm running it with cucumber!

Comment: Dave, I don't know what that means... it's all running command-line, there is no user interface. I want to replace the default "Execution expired" message of the Timeout module by "Err, timeout, ouch" and write a test that verifies this.

Comment: Is the code you showed in a Cucumber step definition or in the program you're testing? That is, by "command-line", do you mean that you're testing a command-line app that does things that time out, or do you just mean that you're running Cucumber on the command line and something in your Cucumber stack is timing out?

Answer (score 1):

Gherkin isn't the place where the magic happens.  The magic happens in the step definition files where you use Ruby, selenium, RSpec and other technologies (e.g.Capybara) to create the desired behaviors.  So to rephrase your question, "How can I test a timeout exception given a cucumber, ruby, RSpec and selenium implementation?"

Selenium has the concept of implicit waits.  That is, the duration over which selenium retries an operation before declaring failure.  You can control implicit waits by setting the following in your env.rb:

```
# Set the amount of time the driver should wait when searching for elements
driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 20

# Sets the amount of time to wait for an asynchronous script to finish
# execution before throwing an error. If the timeout is negative, then the
# script will be allowed to run indefinitely.
driver.manage.timeouts.script_timeout = 20

# Sets the amount of time to wait for a page load to complete before throwing an error.
# If the timeout is negative, page loads can be indefinite.
driver.manage.timeouts.page_load = 20
```

The units are seconds. You will need to set implicit_wait higher than your 'Err, timeout, ouch' timeout. Think.

I believe that WebDriver throws **Error::TimeOutError** when a wait time is exceed. Your code throws, what? Timeout::Error?  So in the rescue sections:

```
Given(/^ .... $/ do
  ...
  rescue Error::TimeOutError => e
    @timeout_exception = "Error::TimeOutError"
  end
  rescue Timeout::Error => f
    @timeout_exception = "Err, timeout, ouch"
  end
end

Then(/^the output should be 'Err, timeout, ouch'$/) do |expectedException|
  expect(@timeout_exception).to eq(expectedException), "Err, timeout, ouch"
end
```

The above assumes that you are using rspec/exceptions, i.e RSpec 3.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to be able to execute the code that needs testing in such a way that the timeout be guaranteed. It's one option to call the cli and set up config files and whatnot but you would be much better off if you can call just the relevant part of the code from your step definition directly.

Next, you want to be able to test the outcome of your 'When' steps in your 'Then' steps. You enclose the actual call in the 'When' step in a 'try' block and store the result as well as any exception somewhere where the 'Then' step will be able to do assertions on them.

Something along the line (please excuse the syntax):

```
Given(/a configuration that will cause a timeout/) do
  sharedContext.config = createConfigThatWillCauseTimeout()

When(/a command is executed/) do
  begin:
    sharedContext.result = executeCommand(sharedContext.config)
  rescue Exception => ex
    sharedContext.exception = ex

Then(/there should have been a Timeout/) do
  logContent = loadLogContent(sharedContext.config)
  assert sharedContext.exception.is_a?(Timeout::Error)
  assert logContent.contains("Err, timeout, ouch")
```